# Does the Image of a Loop under Contraction contain a Disc?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have a point $x \in X$, where $X$ is a Hausdorff space.  Let $J$ be an embedded copy of the circle $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset X$ containing $x$, and let $F$ be a deformation retract of $J$ onto $x$ in $X$.  Define the "trace" $tr(F)$ of $F$ to be all points $y \in X$ such that there are $j \in J, t \in [0,1]$ satisfying $F(j,t) = y$.  In other words, it's the "full image of $J$ under $F$" in $X$.

Let $D$ denote the closed unit disc in the plane, and $S$ its boundary.

> Is there an embedding $i: D \rightarrow tr(F)$ such that $x \in i(S)$?

The question of whether there's a continuous extension to $D$ has been answered a couple times on here, but I'm wondering if contracted loops carve out a disc.  Note that this makes no sense for general contractible spaces, e.g. trees.  This is also weaker than asking if every such loop bounds a disc, which should be impossible by gluing a couple wild arcs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ together (someone correct me if I'm wrong on that, not my area; they might have to be extra-wild ones).

If it's false, what are some sufficient conditions?  Maybe metric $X$ and *strong* deformation retract?

Comment: It's unlikely to be true. (A possible approach would be to use linear contractions of wild circles in $R^3$.) Why do you need it?

Comment: What is the trace of a wild circle under a sequence of linear contractions?  It remains one-dimensional?  It's not a result I need, actually; I am just trying to understand some of the geometric/dynamical implications of the homeomorphism of the group of the plane being locally contractible, as opposed to merely locally path-connected.  I am wondering about the existence of something like a "holomorphic motion of isotopies" - though just a topological version, not analytic.

Comment: No, it is 2-dimensional, but, I am guessing, it has too many self-intersections of the map of the disk.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess you are right concerning self-intersections, but it is hard to understand what possible contractions look like. Perhaps it depends on the choice of a contraction.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I was thinking about the standard linear contraction; but maybe one should use a curve which is wild at every point.

Comment: $\Pi_2$ is a two-dimensional continuum containing no discs, correct?  (it's getting VERY outside my wheelhouse, now; that might not be accurate).  How do loops in it behave?

Comment: When you write that "$F$ is a deformation retract of $J$ onto $x$", do you mean that $F$ is a homotopy from the identity map on $J$ to the constant map $J \mapsto x$?

Comment: It's kinda the same thing, my $F$ (which will exist iff your $F$ does) acts on $J \times I$, rather than on the maps.  I used this to define the trace more easily.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment. You ask whether
for each contraction $F : J \times I \to X$ of $J$ to some $x \in J$ there exists an embedded disk $D' \subset tr(F)$ such that $x \in \partial D'$.

This may depend not only on $J$, but also on the choice of $F$. As an example consider any knot $J \subset \mathbb R^3$ ( as wild as you want). Take a disk $D' \subset \mathbb R^3$ with $x \in \partial D'$. There clearly is a homotopy $H: J \times I \to \mathbb R^3$ rel. $x$ such that $H_0 = id$ and $H_1(J) = \partial D'$. Now combine it with the standard contraction of $D'$. Then $F$ has the desired property.

This leaves of course open whether a **given** $F$ has the same property. However, you should consider what you really want to know: Whether each $F$ is "nice" or whether there exists a "nice" $F$.

Comment: Thanks!  I would like to know for an arbitrary $F$ and $J$, though I do have an application in mind.  But it's sort of technical.  I am interested when $X$ is the group of homeomorphisms of the plane in the compact-open topology.  $X$ is locally contractible in this sense: For any $x \in X$ and nbhd $U$, there's a nbhd $V \subset U$ of $x$ s.t. $V$ deforms to $x$ in $U$.  I want to know that I can pick a $V$ and a deformation such that it carves out a disc.